# SQL Server Business Login in a query

Tags: sql-server

I have a query for calculating extra hours given to employees for the amount of years at the company. A new rule has came in where employees who start in the first two weeks of the year, get an additional 8 hours added to there total on the new year.

All others get a day after completion of a full year of the company

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employee]
ADD AwardedLeave AS CAST (CASE WHEN [Apprentice] = 'Yes'THEN 0

                           WHEN [Apprentice] = 'No' THEN CASE 

                                                                 WHEN GETDATE() BETWEEN  DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate]),01,01) AND DATEADD(week,2,DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate]),01,01)) Then 8
                                                                 WHEN GETDATE() BETWEEN  DATEADD(week,2,DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate]),01,01)) AND DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+1,12,31)  THEN 0 
                                                                 WHEN GETDATE() BETWEEN DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+2,01,01) AND DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+2,12,31) THEN 8
                                                                 WHEN GETDATE() BETWEEN DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+3,01,01) AND DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+3,12,31) THEN 16
                                                                 WHEN GETDATE() BETWEEN DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+4,01,01) AND DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+4,12,31) THEN 24
                                                                 WHEN GETDATE() BETWEEN DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+5,01,01) AND DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+5,12,31) THEN 32 
                                                                 WHEN GETDATE() BETWEEN DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+6,01,01) AND DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate])+1000,12,31) THEN 40 


                                                            END 
                      END AS DECIMAL(7,3));
```

I'm trying to implement this new rule on the line `WHEN GETDATE() BETWEEN  DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate]),01,01) AND DATEADD(week,2,DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate]),01,01)) Then 8` but the problem I'm have is that this adds the hours immediately not on the following year. Is there a way to add the hours after the end of the year.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of validating the year, try validating the month and day so it's the first 15 days of January:

```
WHEN
    MONTH(GETDATE()) = 1 AND DAY(GETDATE()) BETWEEN 1 AND 15 THEN 8
```

I highly recommend creating a [calendar table](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/calendar/145206/) if you work with complex date logics.